# Condition based on Boolean variable c#

Tags: c#, linq

This is just a wondering question for the c# language. I have checked in the MSDN operators and can't see anything close.

When I use LINQ to XML to retrieve some elements, I am passing some lambda expressions in WHERE methods to select specific elements.

But I can see that I am using the following statement which annoys me a bit.

```
 bool myCondition;




// some codes
  var elements = xDocument.Descendants("items").
                   Where(x=>x.Attribute("id")!=null&&
                  (myCondition)x.Element("blah").Value=="blah":
                    x.Element("blah").Value!="blah").ToList();
```

But somehow I keep writing to code as below(no idea why :)):

```
// some codes
  var elements = xDocument.Descendants("items").
                   Where(x=>x.Attribute("id")!=null&&
                  x.Element("blah").Value?myCondition="blah").ToList();
```

I kind of see the boolean myCondition as !(exclamation mark) or =(equal sign).
if true then = if false then !.

I just wonder would that be any possibility in the future to add these types of operators? or there are some better operators that would shorten my condition?

Would this work with any other programming language out there? maybe javascript?

and if you are downgrading then please tell why.

Comment: I don't get what the question is and what you are trying to do. You would need to pass bool condition inside the Where parameter. The first code block you are missing `?` after  `(myCondition)`. The  second block does not pass bool condition, `myCondition="blah"` would be error.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. What I am trying to do is to shorten the amount of code I am writing. depending on a boolean value I make the check whether it should returns the elements where attribute value equal something or not equal something.

Answer (score 1):

You can already express that condition in C# without conditional operator:

```
myCondition?
    xDocument.Element("item").Value=="blah":
    xDocument.Element("item").Value!="blah"
```

is the same as:

```
myCondition == (xDocument.Element("item").Value == "blah")
```

Whether it is more readable is open question. You may consider having helper method with good name instead.